# .htaccess MOD_REWRITE subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an exact copy of my production server and want to use it as development.  I don't want to change any code on the site ( Links, ..etc ).  Is it possible to keep the server pointed to itself with MOD_REWRITE?

```
www.blah.com         => dev.blah.com
blah.com             => dev.blah.com
http://www.blah.com  => dev.blah.com
https://www.blah.com => dev.blah.com
```

Comment: So you have links in your content at `dev.blah.com` that point to `www.blah.com` and you want htaccess to change the outgoing content of your pages?

Comment: @Jon Lin - yes dev.blah.com is an exact copy for blah.com but they are on 2 different servers.  I want to use dev.blah.com for testing purposes but all its links are redirecting to blah.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change *outgoing* content with mod_rewrite, it only affects incoming content. And if your link on dev looks like:

```
<a href="http://www.blah.com/some-page.html">
```

Then when you click on it with your browser, the request is sent to `www.blah.com` and your dev box is completely out of the loop. You need to make it so your content never points to any other site except `dev.blah.com`. And if you don't want to change the actual content, then you need to use a proxy and filter the content. There's an apache module called [mod_proxy_html](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) which has some [documentation](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) for how to change outgoing content, like your links.

You're going to want to look at the `ProxyHTMLURLMap` and then make sure your links are set to what you want using `ProxyHTMLLinks`.

Comment: This answer is great, looks like what I want to do can be done.  I tried playing with the ProxyHTMLURLMap & ProxyHTMLLinks but am having a tough time ( Not an expert with Apache but know my way around ).  Are there any pointers you can give me?  Thanks again for you help & Time